# Force close on AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I am trying to wait until the splash  AsyncTask will get the result from the server so the main activity will continue, on my splash screen I have some GUI with a loading process bar and so on.

but when I run it I get force close. 
Here is my main activity code:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
 {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
     new Thread() { public void run() 
     {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 splash  splash=(tools.splash) new splash(first.this).execute();
                 int waited = 0;
                 while(splash.running && (waited< getResources().getInteger(R.integer.splashTimeOut)))
                 {
                     try {
                         wait(100);
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         if(splash.running) {
                             waited += 100;
                         }
                         // nextActivity=splash.newActivity;
                     }
                     Intent intent = null;
                     try {
                         intent = new Intent(first.this,Class.forName("activities.third"));
                     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                         // TODD Auto-generated catch block
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }

              });
          }
      }.start();
```

from log cat

```
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
  09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at activities.first$1$1$1.run(first.java:54)
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-26 13:41:26.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think its something with wait.
hope you can help.

Comment: -1 after asking 56 questions you don't know to add logcat in question

Comment: please post the whole code + log. I am pretty sure you get the exception at that line thread.stop . That function is not supported any more. There are better ways to implement a splash screen. Search after splash screen without threads.

Comment: what's the point of a thread in which you call runonuithread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize with the object that you're calling the `wait()` on. In this case, you should be able to say

```
synchronized(this){
    wait(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`runOnUiThread` runs on UI thread. You are not authorized to block it like you do by calling successive wait(100);

Also, there is no Asynctask in your code...